# Can webhook target GCP PubSub directly?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, webhooks, google-cloud-pubsub

We're using webhooks to listen to Jira issue events.  Anytime activity on a ticket occurs, the JIRA API notifies an HTTP endpoint running inside a Google Cloud Function.  In this Cloud Function, we are simply forwarding the request unaltered into Pub/Sub via:

```
def forward_to_pubsub(request):

    publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient()
    topic_path = publisher.topic_path(project_id, topic_id)

    # Request body contains user, project, issue basically everything we care about
    jira_body = request.json
    publisher.publish(topic_path, data=json.dumps(jira_body).encode('utf-8'))
```

This seems like an unneeded hop.  Is there anyway to configure Pub/Sub to be the target of a HTTP webhook?  Can't figure out from docs either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible. Pub/Sub topics don't have corresponding HTTP endpoints that can be used as webhooks. If you want to trigger a Pub/Sub topic from an end-user application, you need to use a front-end server between them:

[image]

See https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/overview#endpoints for more details.

Answer (score 3):

It is actually possible to publish messages to a Pub/Sub topic directly over HTTP using the REST API. From the quickstart guide at https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publisher#rest -

> To publish a message, send a POST request like the following:

```
POST  https://pubsub.googleapis.com/v1/projects/PROJECT_ID/topics/TOPIC_ID:publish
Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)
```

> Replace the following:

- PROJECT_ID: the project ID of the project with the topic
- TOPIC_ID: the ID of the topic

> Specify the following fields in the request body:

```
{
"messages": [
  {
    "attributes": {
      "KEY": "VALUE",
      ...
    },
    "data": MESSAGE_DATA,
  }
]
}
```

> Replace the following:

- KEY: the key of a message attribute
- VALUE: the value for the key of the message attribute
- MESSAGE_DATA: a base64-encoded string with the message data

> If the request is successful, the response is a JSON object with the message ID. The following example is a response with a message ID:

```
{
  "messageIds": [
    "19916711285"
  ]
}
```

> After you publish a message, the Pub/Sub service returns the message ID to the publisher.

There is also a [REST API reference](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest) and an [overview of service endpoints and common instructions](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/service_apis_overview) when working with Google REST APIs which should be helpful.

Please note that publish requests have to confirm to the projects.topic.publish [method specification](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.topics/publish) and so would still need to be transformed from the JIRA webhook notification.